# order of events in Ember.js (applicationController and route)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm fetching the current-user from a meta tag in the ApplicationController init event:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['currentUser'],

  init: function() {
    'use strict';

    this._super();

    var attributes = $('meta[name="current-user"]').attr('content');

    if (attributes) {
      this.set('controllers.currentUser.content', App.User.create().setProperties(JSON.parse(attributes)));
    }
  },
```

And in each route where a user needs to be authenticated I have a redirect hook that should redirect if the currentUser is not set:

```
App.UserEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    if (this.controllerFor('currentUser').get('isSignedIn') === false) {
      this.transitionTo('user.login');
    }
  }
});
```

The issue is that the Route redirect event is firing before the ApplicationController.init.

What is the proper way to get this going?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ApplicationController.init()` this logic belongs in a route. Something like this should work:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    var attributes = $('meta[name="current-user"]').attr('content');
    if (attributes) {
      var user = App.User.create().setProperties(JSON.parse(attributes));
      this.controllerFor('currentUser').set('content', user);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Is there a best way to avoid having to code this in every single route?

Comment: It should only be required in App.ApplicationRoute